# A question about compact and complete metric spaces

Tags: metric-spaces

I have a question about compact and complete metric space.

These two concepts how related to each other.

Is  compact metric space complete?

If the question is elementary I apologize you.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For metric spaces, compact means "every sequence has a convergent subsequence".  Complete means "every Cauchy sequence is convergent".

For any metric space, a Cauchy sequence is convergent if it has a convergent subsequence.

So, if a space is compact, then every Cauchy sequence has a convergent subsequence, and is thus itself convergent.  So, every compact space is complete.

Comment: OK. Thank you so much.

Comment: @utya please accept the answer if you found the answer helpful (by pressing the check mark). :)

Comment: But (on the other side) not every complete metric space is compact.